How to test the new esbuild version (v.0.21.0 with decorators) with Vite?
Could you help me to run Vite with the most recent esbuild v0.21.0 release?
I guess I must alter the vite.config.js, but I could not find anything in the docs.
I try to test the new decorators proposal with Vite.
https://github.com/evanw/esbuild/releases/tag/v0.21.0

You can just add an overrides section to your package.json, that enforces a newer esbuild version and run npm install afterwards. It should look similar to this:
{
  // removed irrelevant stuff

  "devDependencies": {
    "vite": "^5.1.4"
  },
  "overrides": {
    "esbuild": "^0.21.0"
  }
}

It forces npm to use this version as a peer dependency instead of the version requested by vite.

that didn't work for me.  vite seems to include its own version of esbuild (0.20.2) in node_modules/vite/node_modules/esbuild. Do you know how to override that?

Are you using npm or some version of yarn? If you use yarn you have to use the resolutions in the package.json instead. See here for the version 1 docs https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/selective-version-resolutions/ and here for the doc for newer versions: https://yarnpkg.com/configuration/manifest#resolutions
